# Are Javascript/ jQuery range sliders accessible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accessibility

I'm working on a site that needs to meet AA accessibility. One page has a large list of results where filters can be applied using Javascript to reduce the number of results. The designs call for a range slider to filter by a dollar value.

Do range sliders (such as jQuery UI Slider) have any accessibility constraints or are there established workarounds? Are they accessible 'out of the box'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to make sure the *form* elements are made accessible to the user so they may manipulate it. So without having to literally click on the drag icon and dragging it along the slider, because they may not see the visual feedback as to how far along the slider they are at and what the current value is.

In order to make sure the sliders are accessible, you'd need to use ones that use valid *form* elements to represent the values. For example the one that binds to a `<select>` (http://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms).

I've made one in the past that binds to radio buttons so dragging the slider is automatically selecting the radio buttons, here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/J4eL3/